# secedit.exe при импорте не импортируются настройки политики аудита

Tags: cmd, windows-10, bat

При вызове команды
`secedit /configure /cfg %file% /db defltbase.sdb /verbose /log logs.inf`

все завершается без ошибки, но импортируются настройки политики паролей нормально, а вот настройки политики аудита не настраиваются.

Если в **secpol.msc** пробую импортировать вручную с того же файла, все настраивается нормально.

Как добиться настройки политики аудита помощью шаблона и **secedit**?